# How resistant are stream ciphers like Salsa20 or ChaCha in a post-quantum world?

Tags: stream-cipher, post-quantum-cryptography, chacha, salsa20

What kind of quantum computer would be required, if it is possible to break such ciphers?

Comment: I assume you're talking about 256-bit keys, not 128-bit or 80-bit?

Answer (score 5):

There is no known quantum attack better than the generic [Grover attack](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9605043) on Salsa20 and ChaCha, which is inconsequential because it would take $2^{128}$ sequential steps.  Even if [parallelized](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9711070) $p$ ways to run in marginally less time, a factor of $\sqrt p$ improvement, it would cost *more*, also by a factor of $\sqrt p$, than the cost to run a quantum computer for $2^{128}$ steps.  Even if you were satisfied with breaking the first of $t$ targets for $t \ll p$, you would get only a $\sqrt[4] t$ cost reduction in [the best known multi-target attack](https://cr.yp.to/papers.html#groverrho).

The same is true for AES key recovery, SHA-256 preimage search, *etc.*  [More on quantum attacks on various kinds of hash functions.](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/59390)